# Cannot use the substr function after using erase

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to solve a problem on [usaco](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=526) which is give a string **S** and another string smaller than it **T** and ask to remove all the occurences of **T** in **S**.

so my approach is to iterate over **S** and check whether the last substring of it is equal to **T**, if that is the case i will erase it, but the problem is after i erase the first occurence, the substr function is not working anymore.

Here is te code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream fin ("censor.in");
ofstream fout ("censor.out");

string s,t; fin >> s >> t;

int n = s.size(), m = t.size();

string censored;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    censored += s[i];

    if(censored.size() > m && censored.substr(i - (m-1) , m) == t)
    {
        censored.erase(i- (m-1), i);
    }
        
}

fout<< censored << '\n';

}
```

and the content of the file censor.in is :

whatthemoommomooooofun
moo

the solution should be:

whatthefun

Comment: Unrelated, but please read: [Why should I **not** `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: After you erase characters from the string, neither the size nor the indexes will no longer match what you originally had. You need to recalculate the string length, as well as the index `i`.

Comment: Yep I geuss am blind thank you so much @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @TedLyngmo, thank you but i am using this code for competitivef programming so its not that big of a problem

Comment: How do you know it's not working any more?

Comment: i used a debugger, but anyway the problem is solved i am trying to figure out how to close it.

Answer (score 0):

After you erase characters from the string, neither the size nor the indexes will no longer match what you originally had. You need to recalculate the string length, as well as the index i.

credit: [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)